# Scale and maintain DIV positions with window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I scale and maintain DIV positions when the browser window is resized using jQuery?

This is what I've done so far. But doesn't do exactly what I need. The positioning is wrong.

```
$(window).resize(function(){    
 for(i=1;i<3;i++){    
  var p = $('#dv'+i);
  var offset = p.offset();    
  var newwidth = $(window).width() / ($('#dv'+i).width());
  var newheight = $(window).height() / ($('#dv'+i).height());

  $('#dv'+i).height(newheight).width(newwidth);
  $('#dv'+i).offset({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left});
 }
});
```

Comment: How come you are using JavaScript to solve this problem. If you put in the right CSS style declarations your DIVs should grow and shrink with the browser window.

Comment: @SimonH: thanks. You mean `width: 100%;` ?

Comment: Not necessarily 100%, if you look at the grid system that popular CSS frameworks like bootstrap implement that should get you most of the way. Unless you are trying to maintain a specific aspect ratio?

Comment: @SimonH: Exactly... I need to maintain the ratio. I'm using bootstraps `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12`. But I'm looking for jquery solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using javascript for resizing and rather try this technique - http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html (if this suits your needs).